# Function doesn't return the right value

Tags: arduino, iot, verification, rfid, nodemcu

To begin with, I'm doing a mini project on the verification of RFID card using NodeMCU. I set up a database and a server to handle all the requests from the client. The problem is, whenever I try to verify a valid card, the function that handles it keeps returning the wrong value.

To be clear, here is my main loop:

```cpp
void loop() {
  connectToHost();
  key = kpd.getKey();
  card = readCard();
  delay(200);
  //check for card status
  if(verifyCard(card)){
    Serial.println("Card is valid");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Invalid Card");
  }
  //check connection status
  if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTION_LOST){
    connectToWiFi();
  }
}
```

The main loop calls this function:

```cpp
boolean verifyCard(String uid){
  String url = "/ECafe/terminal_verify.php?uid=";
  url += uid;
  // This will send the request to the server
  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
    "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
    "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
    }
    yield();
  }
  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while (client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    //if string contains echo from php file
    if(line.indexOf("Valid")>0){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
    yield();
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Closing connection");
}
```

I intentionally put a valid card UID in the database just to test this function. Yet, it keeps returning false. I'm sure that the response from the server is "Valid". I suspect that the function doesn't even wait for the response from the server and returns a false value because the interval between the GET request is sent and the response is returned is too short. Is that because of the if condition in the main loop? See the attachment for the serial monitor output.

[image]

Comment: Taking out the if condition from while(client.available()) loop seems to fix the problem. But sometime I encounter the Client Timeout loop and hv to reset the module to fix it.

Comment: What should be returned if you get message "Closing connection" at the end of function? There is no return statement.

Comment: That message do nothing. I should remove it before posting it here.

Comment: If you dont call return statement in this execution path, some random value will be returned

Comment: Also asked at: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=534412 If you're going to do that then please be considerate enough to add links to the other places you cross posted. This will let us avoid wasting time due to duplicate effort and also help others who have the same questions and find your post to discover all the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your function is flawed.

```
  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while (client.available()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    //if string contains echo from php file
    if(line.indexOf("Valid")>0){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
```

When the code reads the first line, and it doesn't contain `Valid`, it will fail and return `false`. So your code will **ALWAYS** return false, as I doubt that the first line returned is `Valid`...

```
    }
    yield();
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Closing connection");
```

The rest of this code is never executed. "Closing connection" is never printed right?